# What outfits will keep Mario warm?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

There are some worlds that are cold, causing Mario to shiver.  I noticed if you put on the aviator cap and coat, he will stop shivering.

What other clothing sets will keep Mario warm?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of useless question I love

Comment: I've expanded on Pyrite's answer below. Is there any more information you would like me to add?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The Aviator Outfit, the Snow Outfit, and the Space Suit are the only clothing sets that will keep Mario warm in cold environments.

In addition, these outfits will keep Mario cool in hot environments: Caveman Outfit, Boxer Shorts, Swimwear, the Space Suit and the Resort Outfit.

Comment: Does this affect anything in gameplay? Or its just an animation difference?

Comment: @Fredy31 No gameplay difference.

Comment: What if you mix and match?

Comment: @Kroltan what do you mean, no gameplay difference??!?!? You don't want Mario to freeze to death, do you??

Comment: @MCMastery he'll only freeze to death if you swim in cold water, and that will happen regardless of clothing.

Comment: @user2357112 I _think_ it's only the body item that matters, but I'm not 100% sure on that. I've worn the Resort Shirt + Captain's Hat in the Sand Kingdom and Mario wasn't hot.

Comment: @Pyritie Please research it and expand your answer. This is a VERY CRITICAL ISSUE!! :D

Comment: It's obviously not a very good space suit if it doesn't keep you cool in hot environments.

Comment: @Alfro Based on my research, hats have no effect on Mario's temperature.

Comment: My favourite bit is that the caption on the snow gear is “After decades of snow levels, finally, a warm coat!”

Comment: @Fredy31 What do you think this is, Breath of the Wild?! :)

Comment: @Pyritie Can you update this in light of the new costumes in 1.2? Do any of them keep Mario hot/cool?

Comment: @DonielF I haven't played any of the new patches I'm afraid :(

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It's still pretty bad. I mean, it lets (cold) water go trough it and kill you! What about air or radiation in space?

Answer (score 34):

After reading [Pyrite's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320745/181240), I decided to do a bit more experimentation with the outfits. I visited each kingdom in the game to see how the weather affected Mario's well-being.

Mario has 3 different states depending on the weather and his outfit.

- **Cold**: Mario will shiver immediately when idling.
- **Normal**: Standard idle animations.
- **Warm**: Mario wipes sweat off his forehead and fans himself after idling for a few seconds.

## Outfits that keep Mario warm

- **Aviator Outfit**: (Lost Kingdom - 10 purple coins)
- **Snow Suit**: (Snow Kingdom - 10 purple coins)
- **Space Suit**: (Moon Kingdom - 10 purple coins)

## Outfits that keep Mario cool

- **Caveman Outfit** (Cascade Kingdom - 10 purple coins)
- **Boxer Shorts** (Any Kingdom - 1,000 gold coins)
- **Poncho** (Sand Kingdom - 10 purple coins)
- **Swimwear** (Lake Kingdom - 10 purple coins)
- **Resort Outfit** (Seaside Kingdom - 10 purple coins)
- **Football Uniform** (Moon Kingdom - 150 gold coins)

## Cold Kingdoms (Mario shivers)

- **Sand Kingdom (night/underground)** - Tostarena
- **Snow Kingdom** - Shiveria

## Warm Kingdoms (Mario fans himself)

- **Sand Kingdom (day)*** - Tostarena
- **Lost Kingdom** - Forgotten Isle
- **Seaside Kingdom** - Bubblaine
- **Luncheon Kingdom** - Mount Volbano

#### Notes

- Mario will fan himself in the Sand Kingdom *regardless* of what outfit he is wearing.
- Mario will fan himself when wearing a warm outfit in a non-cold kingdom.
- Hats do not seem to have any effect on Mario's reaction to the weather.

[Thanks to IGN for the list of outfit locations and prices](http://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-odyssey/Outfits_and_Costumes).

Comment: What about the outfit you get for completing the 503 moon objective? That one plays weirdly with animation. (Not being more specific to avoid spoilers)

Comment: @CAD97 *That* outfit does not change Mario’s animations for hot or cold weather. (I assume you meant the retro one)

Comment: I'm not certain on mario always sweating in the sand kingdom. I'm fairly sure I wore the resort outfit there and wasn't sweating. I'll double check.

Comment: The Sand Kingdom's underground areas also all count as cold areas, regardless of it being day or night above.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Can you update this in light of the new outfits in 1.2? Do any of those keep Mario hot/cool?